# How to train a neural network with the float type of data(bounding box)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train my model with the images having multiple bonding boxes but the issue arises when train with the csv file obtained from the json annotated file. The error is:

> Cast string to float is not supported [[node
> categorical_crossentropy/Cast (defined at
> C:\Users\Desktop\untitled35.py:150) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_4346]  Unimplemented: Cast string to
> float is not supported.

Need help to solve this. I have tried to train it on data where have single value in a column I mean not separated by commas it works fine.

```py
    images = glob.glob("C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/Images/*.ppm")
    images = sorted(images,key= os.path.getmtime)
    train_image =[]
    x1 = []
    depth = 10
    for i in tqdm(range(len(images))):
        timg = image.load_img(images[i])
        image1= timg.resize((40, 40))
       img = image.img_to_array(image1)
       train_image.append(img)   
    print(len(train_image)) 
    IMG = np.array(train_image)
    plt.imshow(IMG[2])
    print(IMG.shape)
    train_image = np.expand_dims(train_image,4)
    x = train_image.transpose(4,0,1,2,3)
    print("shape of x,",x.shape)
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/MSI/Desktop/data_js1.csv')  
    Y_In = np.array(df)
    Y_In = Y_In.reshape(1,-1)
    batch_size = 40
    n_images = 40
    seq_length = 20
    Input_shape1 =(40,40,40,3) 
    num_classes = 1
    model = Sequential()  
    X_train = x
    Y_train = Y_In
    print(Y_train.shape,"y_train shape")    
    print(X_train.shape,"x shape") 

    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(1, 1, 1), input_shape = 
    Input_shape1))#(X.shape[1:])))      #1280x720x240x32
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2)))                    
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))                     
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))                   
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv3D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), 
    padding='same'))                  #320x180x60x128
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(40, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy,optimizer='Adam',metrics ['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())
    history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=40, epochs=3, verbose=1, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: here is the data of CSV: [[71.78683385579937, 72.01253918495298], [111.5987460815047, 251.94984326018812]] one row as a sample is being shared

Comment: You are trying to predict bounding boxes of objects in images, right? Why has your last layer 40 output neurons with softmax activation? And why categorical-cross-entropy loss? This is not a classification task, right?

Comment: yes i want to predict the bounding boxes along with labels in test form.

Comment: Ok then you would need to adapt your current architecture. If I see correctly, right now  your labels are the bounding boxes, but the output of your model are class labels.

Comment: yes class labels with bounding box